# How to echo all column values of an id into rows using mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I am on the way to create a webform for education related activity. My mysql table looks like this

```
+----+--------+---------+-----------+---------+-----------------------------
| id |schlname| trname  | pay  |oa |gross|trname2|pay2|oa2|gross2| -----etc
+----+--------+---------+-----------+---------+-----------------------------
|  1 |Greatedn|  Bredier| 1000 | 25|1025|Pastiur |1000| 25|1025  |
   2 |Meritedn|  Paskin | 1000 | 25|1025|Blazer  |1000| 25|1025  |
+----+--------+---------+-----------+---------+----------------------------
```

I need to take report using php query using echo statement. My expected report should be like this

```
+----+--------+---------+-----------+-------
| id |schlname| trname  | pay  | oa |gross |
+----+--------+---------+-----------+-------
|  1 |Greatedn|  Bredier| 1000 | 25 |1025  |
                 Pastiur |1000 | 25 |1025  |
                 etc...
                 etc...
   2 |Meritedn|  Paskin | 1000 | 25 |1025  |
                 Blazer |1000  | 25 |1025  |
                 etc...
                 etc..
```

Your valuable ideas are expected to complete my study

Comment: you mean you need to get some of your mysql table's columns and output them into a html table using php ?

Comment: Just throwing this out there: var_dump can pretty much dump out all your variables in JSON format. But using fetch_all on a query will store your table in everything you want.

Comment: let me guess. you have a `pay2`, `pay3`, .... `payN` structure? that's incredibly inefficient. if you had a properly normalized table, you wouldn't even need to ask this question. you're trying to do an "unpivot" query...

Comment: Have you attempted to write the code yourself? Please post what you've tried to indicate some effort on your part.

Answer (score 0):

This is untested, but I'd go somewhere along these lines, maybe a double for loop if you want to make it look pretty

```
        require "conn.php";
        $sql = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM yourtablename WHERE 1");
        $sql->execute();
        $data_storage = $sql->fetch_all();
        for($i = 0; $i < $data_storage->rowCount(); $i++) {
            echo $data_storage[$i];
        }
```

Let me know if this answers your question. Not quite sure if this is what you're asking for.

Answer (score 0):

let me know if something fails ;)

```
<?php

$con=mysqli_connect("#","#","#","#");

if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

<div id="container">
<br><br>
<section class="column1" style="font-weight:bold;">Reference</section>
<section class="column1" style="font-weight:bold;">Language Combination</section>
<section class="column1" style="font-weight:bold;">Customer Delivery Date</section>
<section class="column1" style="font-weight:bold;">Project Status</section>
<br><br>

$result1 = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE schlname="Greatedn" ");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result1))
{
?> <br><br> <section class="column2"> <?php echo $row['id']; ?> </section> <?php
?> <br><br> <section class="column2"> <?php echo $row['schlname']; ?> </section> <?php
?> <br><br> <section class="column2"> <?php echo $row['trname']; ?> </section> <?php
?> <br><br> <section class="column2"> <?php echo $row['pay']; ?> </section> <?php
?> <br><br> <section class="column2"> <?php echo $row['oa']; ?> </section> <?php
?> <br><br> <section class="column2"> <?php echo $row['gross']; ?> </section> <?php
?><section class="clearboth"></section><br><br><?php
}

$result2 = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE schlname="Meritedn" ");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result2))
{
?> <br><br> <section class="column2"> <?php echo $row['id']; ?> </section> <?php
?> <br><br> <section class="column2"> <?php echo $row['schlname']; ?> </section> <?php
?> <br><br> <section class="column2"> <?php echo $row['trname']; ?> </section> <?php
?> <br><br> <section class="column2"> <?php echo $row['pay']; ?> </section> <?php
?> <br><br> <section class="column2"> <?php echo $row['oa']; ?> </section> <?php
?> <br><br> <section class="column2"> <?php echo $row['gross']; ?> </section> <?php
?><section class="clearboth"></section><br><br><?php
}

mysqli_close($con);

?>

</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.column 1 {
float: left;
width: 15%;
overflow: hidden;
}

.container {
//Some cool stuff here
}

.clearboth {
clear: both;
}
```